# running PowerShell as admin in the current folder

Tags: powershell

trying to find a quick way to running powershell as admin in the current folder

I can run powershell as admin from the start bar

but to run in the current folder using alt+f/s/a it doesn't work

am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: There's no way to achieve this "easily". You'd need to update registry to do it. Cannot test it right now, so will not paste any links, but quick search could give you an idea

Comment: [this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/60177-add-open-powershell-window-here-administrator-windows-10-a.html) might help